# Will Kubernetes refresh OIDC tokens only after it expires?

Tags: openid, kubernetes

With Kubernetes configured to point to an external OpendID provider, it seems through browsing through the code that Kubernetes makes a call to the OpendID provider to get a refresh token.  It expects an `id_token` to come back.  It seems that Kubernetes respects the expire time for the bearer token and not make a call to the OpendID provider until the bearer token expires.

Is that the correct description of how the refresh tokens work in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes doesn't have any concept of refresh tokens because the Kubernetes API server isn't a client of the OpenID provider, it simply validates `id_token`s issues for a specific client.

Clients of the OpenID provider which wish to talk to the API server on the end user's behalf must manage the refresh tokens to issue more `id_token`s as the current one expires. The API server wont do it for you.

Comment: `kubectl config set-credentials USER_NAME \
   --auth-provider=oidc \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=( issuer url ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-id=( your client id ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=( your client secret ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=( your refresh token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority=( ca certificate ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=id-token=( your id_token ) \
   --auth-provider-arg=extra-scopes=( comma separated list of scopes to add to "openid email)` What values should i use for the refresh-id and id-token parameters?